# Is there any way to open docx/docs files within the flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, docx

I've tried many plugins to load docx files within the flutter app, but no one has given me a proper solution, and the plugins only work if the device has a support app for loading docs files.

I also tried a converter plugin to convert a doc file to a pdf file so that I could open it in my flutter application.

If anyone has any ideas on how I can load docx files inside the flutter app or how I can convert docs to pdf so that I can load pdf in it, please let me know.

I can't put code here because I tried a lot of plugins and ways to do it and none of them work for me, so I'm asking for suggestions.

Comment: you can try this package =https://pub.dev/packages/open_file#-readme-tab-

Comment: @Babul This is not woking for me cause open_file opens file in support application and i want to open file inside my flutter app